# Наследование и синглетон

Tags: php

Есть `singleton` и созданы два класса `A` и `B` наследующие от класса `core`.

Вопрос в следующем:

1. Класса `А` дочерний от родительского класса `core`,
2. Класс  `B` дочерний от родительского класса `A`,

Почему же `getInstance()` для дочернего класса `B` не получает значение переменной `a` ?

```
class core{

    public $a;

    public static function getInstance() {
        static $instance = null;

        if(is_null($instance)) {
            $instance = new static();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    protected final function __construct() { $this->a = 1; }
    protected final function __clone() {}
    protected final function __wakeup() {}

}

class A extends core{}

class B extends A{}

$a      = A::getInstance();
$a_new  = A::getInstance();
$b      = B::getInstance();

var_dump($a);        //1
var_dump($a_new);    //1
var_dump($b);        //1

$a->a = 2;
var_dump($a->a);       //2
var_dump($a_new->a);   //2
var_dump($b->a);       //1   ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что

```
$a === $a_new //так как получены из класса A, следовательно и свойство $a будет одно на двоих
```

и

```
$a !== $b //так как получены из разных классов (A и B), следовательно и свойство $a будет для каждого свое
```

Comment: Т.е. получается, что каждый класс имеет свою "область", даже после наследования эта "область" не "сливается в одну область", а лишь добавляется к дочернему классу в виде "области методов и свойств" (т.е. область реализации)?

Comment: @kosinus777, все, что вызывается/задается через $this, относится **только** к конкретному объекту. У "соседей" и родителей ничего не изменится.

Answer (score 0):

Ответьте на простой вопрос - `$a` и `$b` являются одной и той же сущностью?

Comment: Нет не является, т.к. создается уже другой объект. спасибо!